LWC Cast Exception Error help
I am having an issue with sending a Save command to the controller of an LWC.
Everything works up to the save point but when I click Save the error is presented:

Error saving game: aura://ApexActionController.execute: ServerServiceImpl::unwrapAction Class Cast Exception: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.util.Map (java.lang.String and java.util.Map are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

The browser console shows the message "Saving game with data:" but the debug logs do not contain the logging from the controller.
What am I doing wrong?
The HTML:
<div class="slds-m-around_medium">
    <lightning-button
        label="Save Selection"
        variant="brand"
        onclick={handleSave}
        disabled={isGameCreated}>
    </lightning-button>
</div>

The JS:
handleSave() {
    if (this.isGameCreated) {
        this.error = 'A game is already active. You cannot create another.';
        return;
    }

    const totals = this.attributeRows.reduce((acc, row) => {
        acc[`curr${row.name}`] = row.totalValue || 0;
        return acc;
    }, {});

    console.log('Saving game with data:', {
        lordName: this.selectedLord,
        steadingName: this.selectedSteading,
        totals,
    });

    saveGameRecord(
        this.selectedLord,
        this.selectedSteading,
        totals.currAttack || 0,
        totals.currDefense || 0,
        totals.currIncome || 0,
        totals.currStamina || 0,
        totals.currCost || 0,
        totals.currSize || 0,
        totals.currEfficiency || 0,
        totals.currLoyalty || 0
    )
    .then((gameId) => {
        console.log('Game saved successfully with ID:', gameId);
        this.isGameCreated = true;
        this.gameId = gameId;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error saving game:', error);
        this.error = 'Error saving game: ' + (error.body?.message || error.message);
    });
}

The controller:
@AuraEnabled
public static Id saveGameRecord(String lordName, String steadingName, Decimal currAttack, Decimal currDefense, Decimal currIncome, Decimal currStamina, Decimal currCost, Decimal currSize, Decimal currEfficiency, Decimal currLoyalty) {
    System.debug('saveGameRecord called with:');
    System.debug('lordName=' + lordName);

    longwood__Game__c newGame = new longwood__Game__c(
        longwood__Lord_Name__c = lordName,
        longwood__Steading_Name__c = steadingName,
        longwood__CurrentAttack__c = currAttack,
        longwood__CurrentDefence__c = currDefense,
        longwood__CurrentIncome__c = currIncome,
        longwood__CurrentStamina__c = currStamina,
        longwood__CurrentCost__c = currCost,
        longwood__CurrentSize__c = currSize,
        longwood__CurrentEfficiency__c = currEfficiency,
        longwood__CurrentLoyalty__c = currLoyalty,
        longwood__IsActive__c = true
    );

    insert newGame;
    return newGame.Id;
}


You have to add the parameters in an object:
saveGameRecord({ lordName: this.selectedLord, steadingName: this.selectedSteading, ... })


This works, but gets a new error. Thank you. :)

ok, tell me if I can help you
